# Не могу скачать rtf файл средством php

Tags: php, rtf, download

Вот заголовки которые я использовал

```
  $file = 'http://mysite.com/file/my_file.rtf';
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type:application/rtf');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="freest_file_transfer.rtf"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
             exit;
```

скачивает файл с битым содержимым

Answer (score 1):

Любые вопросы, содержащие слова "скачать файл", хорошо бы начинать решать самостоятельно, с помощью [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) (порт под Windows тоже [имеется](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)).

Стандартное начало включения головы выглядит так:

```
wget -S -o headers.txt "http://mysite.com/file/my_file.rtf"
```

А дальше - анализировать файлы `myfile.rtf` и `headers.txt`

P.S. Вообще, `wget` - инструмент номер один, нет, даже номер ноль! для разработчика, имеющего дело с HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Тут проблема вот в чем (как минимум):

```
$file = 'http://mysite.com/file/my_file.rtf';
...
readfile($file);
```

`readfile()` просто откроет путь, который ему скормили, и вернет все содержимое. Вы же открываете **url**. PHP **сделает лишний запрос** (это плохо само по себе, но я не про это), в ответ на который получит **HTTP-ответ**, который не является вашим файлом, он является HTTP-ответом (точнее, он содержит в себе файл, но далеко не первым байтом). Поэтому клиенту отдается весь HTTP-ответ, включая заголовки, и только потом идет содержимое файла.
Если вопрос "как от этого избавиться" не исчез, то надо **не обращаться к своим файлам по http**, а находить их по обычному пути на файловой системе. Если файл все-таки лежит на удаленном сервере - то сначала скачивать, а потом отдавать. И, если уж к вашему файлу можно обратиться по http, то почему просто не отдать не ссылку?